# How to add a rule in Antlr g4 file to allow writing regular expressions in JavaScript and C#?

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I have ANtlr G4 grammar. I want to it to allow taking first parameter of a function to be the regular expression. I added new regex_Literal. But, it complains about

```
error(50): Expression.g4:149:15: syntax error: '/' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element
error(50): Expression.g4:149:27: syntax error: '/' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

This is how the grammar looks.

```
grammar Expression
  ;

options {
  caseInsensitive = true;
}

// Parser rules.

parse_all: expressionSequence EOF;

expressionSequence: expression (COMMA expression)*;

expression
  : OPEN_PARENS expression CLOSE_PARENS                                                      # Parenthesis
  | MINUS right = expression                                                                 # UnaryMinus
  | NOT right = expression                                                                   # Not
  | functionDeclaration                                                                      # Function
  | left = expression op = (ASTERISK | SLASH) right = expression                             # Arithmetic
  | left = expression op = (PLUS | MINUS) right = expression                                 # Arithmetic
  | left = expression op = (EQ | NE | GT | GTE | LT | LTE) right = expression                # Comparison
  | left = expression op = TILDE right = expression                                          # Contains
  | left = expression IN right = expression_array                                            # In
  | left = expression op = (AND | OR) right = expression                                     # AndOr
  | condition = expression QUESTIONMARK true_expr = expression COLON false_expr = expression # Ternary
  | ifStatement                                                                              # IfElse
  | expression_array                                                                         # Array
  | field = IDENTIFIER DOT attribute = IDENTIFIER                                            # AttributeAccessor
  | STRING_LITERAL                                                                           # StringLiteral
  | boolean_literal                                                                          # BooleanLiteral
  | IDENTIFIER                                                                               # Identifier
  | numeric_literal                                                                          # NumericLiteral
  | regex_Literal                                                                            # RegexLiteral
  ;

functionDeclaration
  : DOLLAR function_name = IDENTIFIER OPEN_PARENS expressionSequence? CLOSE_PARENS
  ;

conditionalStatement
  : condition = expression QUESTIONMARK true_expr = expression COLON false_expr = expression
  ;

ifStatement
  : IF condition_block (ELSEIF condition_block)* ELSE statement_block
  ;

condition_block: expression THEN statement_block;

statement_block: expression;

expression_array: OPEN_BRACKET expressionSequence CLOSE_BRACKET;

boolean_literal: TRUE # True | FALSE # False;

numeric_literal: NUMBER # Numeric | INTEGER # Integer;

// Lexer rules.

OPEN_BRACKET: '[';
CLOSE_BRACKET: ']';
OPEN_PARENS: '(';
CLOSE_PARENS: ')';

COLON: ':';
COMMA: ',';
DOLLAR: '$';
DOT: '.';
DOUBLE_QUOTE: '"';
QUESTIONMARK: '?';
SEMICOLON: ';';
SINGLE_QUOTE: '\'';
TILDE: '~';

EQ: '=';
NE: '!=';
GT: '>';
GTE: '>=';
LT: '<';
LTE: '<=';

ASTERISK: '*';
MINUS: '-';
PLUS: '+';
SLASH: '/';

AND: 'AND';
OR: 'OR';
NOT: 'NOT';
IN: 'IN';

IF: 'IF';
THEN: 'THEN';
ELSE: 'ELSE';
ELSEIF: 'ELSEIF';

TRUE: 'TRUE';
FALSE: 'FALSE';

NUMBER: ( DIGIT+ DOT DIGIT+ | DIGIT+ DOT | DOT DIGIT+);
INTEGER: DIGIT+;

IDENTIFIER: LETTER+ (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
STRING_LITERAL: DOUBLE_QUOTE (~[\r\n\\"])*? DOUBLE_QUOTE;

fragment LETTER: [A-Z] | '_';
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];

fragment NewLine
  : '\r\n'
  | '\r'
  | '\n'
  | '\u0085' // <Next Line CHARACTER (U+0085)>'
  | '\u2028' //'<Line Separator CHARACTER (U+2028)>'
  | '\u2029' //'<Paragraph Separator CHARACTER (U+2029)>'
  ;

fragment Whitespace
  : UnicodeClassZS //'<Any Character With Unicode Class Zs>'
  | '\u0009'       //'<Horizontal Tab Character (U+0009)>'
  | '\u000B'       //'<Vertical Tab Character (U+000B)>'
  | '\u000C'       //'<Form Feed Character (U+000C)>'
  ;

fragment UnicodeClassZS
  : '\u0020' // SPACE
  | '\u00A0' // NO_BREAK SPACE
  | '\u1680' // OGHAM SPACE MARK
  | '\u180E' // MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
  | '\u2000' // EN QUAD
  | '\u2001' // EM QUAD
  | '\u2002' // EN SPACE
  | '\u2003' // EM SPACE
  | '\u2004' // THREE_PER_EM SPACE
  | '\u2005' // FOUR_PER_EM SPACE
  | '\u2006' // SIX_PER_EM SPACE
  | '\u2008' // PUNCTUATION SPACE
  | '\u2009' // THIN SPACE
  | '\u200A' // HAIR SPACE
  | '\u202F' // NARROW NO_BREAK SPACE
  | '\u3000' // IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
  | '\u205F' // MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
  ;

WHITESPACES: (Whitespace | NewLine)+ -> skip;

regex_Literal: '/' regexContent? '/';

regexContent: ~[/]+ | '/' ~[/]+;

ANY: .;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside parser rules, you can't use character sets/classes. So your `regexContent` rule is invalid, it cannot use `~[/]+`.

Given you also use `/` as adivide-operator, you cannot easily create a lexer rule that matches a regex literal. After all, how can the lexer know if a `/` in the input `x = 1/2/3` is a divide operator, but in `x = /2/` a regex delimiter.

Have a look at how the [JavaScript](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/javascript/javascript/JavaScriptLexer.g4) grammar handles this. Note that inside the lexer, the following code is being used to determine if a `/` is possibly a regex delimiter or not:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the lexer can match a regex literal.
    /// </summary>
    protected bool IsRegexPossible()
    {
        if (_lastToken == null)
        {
            // No token has been produced yet: at the start of the input,
            // no division is possible, so a regex literal _is_ possible.
            return true;
        }

        switch (_lastToken.Type)
        {
            case Identifier:
            case NullLiteral:
            case BooleanLiteral:
            case This:
            case CloseBracket:
            case CloseParen:
            case OctalIntegerLiteral:
            case DecimalLiteral:
            case HexIntegerLiteral:
            case StringLiteral:
            case PlusPlus:
            case MinusMinus:
                // After any of the tokens above, no regex literal can follow.
                return false;
            default:
                // In all other cases, a regex literal _is_ possible.
                return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. So, even after modifying my grammar, is it not possible to add regex to the grammar?

Comment: No, you need to add target specific code to the lexer so it knows when a regex delimiter is possible.

Comment: Do you know where exactly in ExpressionLexer.js file I need to make this change? And should I change my grammar and just handle things at lexer side?

Comment: You can implement your lexer just as the JavaScript lexer is implemented: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/javascript/javascript/JavaScriptLexer.g4